# The graph produced by IPython is not correct

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, matplotlib

I have 2 files `GBM_simulation.py` and `test_GBM.py`.

**GBM_simulation.py**

```
import numpy as np

# Return path as numpy array of length and step predefined

# simulate exact GBM

def GBM(n, dt, s0, r, sigma):
    path = np.zeros(n)
    s_old = s0
    for i in range(n):
        s_new = s_old*np.exp((r-sigma**2/2)*dt + sigma*(dt)**(1/2)*np.random.normal())
        path[i] = s_new
        s_old = s_new
        return path

# simulate Euler scheme GBM:

def Euler_GBM(n, dt, s0, r, sigma):
    path = np.zeros(n)
    s_old = s0
    for i in range(n):
        s_new = s_old*(1 + r*dt + sigma*(dt)**(1/2)*np.random.normal())
        path[i] = s_new
        s_old = s_new
        return path
```

**test_GBM.py**

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import GBM_simulation as sim

s0 = 2
n = 500
r = 1
sigma = 1
dt = 0.001

exact = sim.GBM(n, dt, s0, r, sigma)
euler = sim.Euler_GBM(n, dt, s0, r, sigma)

# Now plot
plt.plot(exact, label = 'Exact')
plt.plot(euler, label = 'Euler')
plt.legend(loc = 'best')
plt.show()
```

However, when I run `test_GBM.py` on IPython console, the graph I get doesn't look correct at all. I tested on Jupyter Notebook (with some minor modifications) and it worked properly. Why does this happen?

[image]

Edit: this is the graph I got on Jupyter notebook

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "it doesn't look correct"? It looks exactly the same on Eclipse. What is the difference to the output in Jupyter notebook? And what were those "minor modifications"?

Comment: I have added the graph on Jupyter Notebook. What I mean by minor modifications are just replacing sim.GBM... by GBM, sim.Euler_GBM by Euler_GBM and there is no line: import GBM_simluation as sim and put these 2 files .py in a notebook.

Comment: Matplotlib only plots what you tell it to plot. There is no way you are plotting the same data points in both examples above. Check your code, you are doing something different somewhere... Also, the plot you say is from jupyter seems to have been done with Seaborn (which actually uses Matplotlib).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't believe that I didn't notice this immediately. Indentation matters - your return statement was inside the loop. The correct function definition is of course:

```
import numpy as np

# Return path as numpy array of length and step predefined

# simulate exact GBM

def GBM(n, dt, s0, r, sigma):
    path = np.zeros(n)
    s_old = s0
    for i in range(n):
        s_new = s_old*np.exp((r-sigma**2/2)*dt + sigma*(dt)**(1/2)*np.random.normal())
        path[i] = s_new
        s_old = s_new
    return path

# simulate Euler scheme GBM:

def Euler_GBM(n, dt, s0, r, sigma):
    path = np.zeros(n)
    s_old = s0
    for i in range(n):
        s_new = s_old*(1 + r*dt + sigma*(dt)**(1/2)*np.random.normal())
        path[i] = s_new
        s_old = s_new
    return path
```

For future reference my debugging procedure - I printed out the values for each single data point in the function loop to see, why the values drop immediately to zero. Et voilà - only one data point was calculated, so something must have been wrong with your loop definition.

Comment: Yessss. What a silly mistake!!! I didn't notice too when I copied pasted the code from the notebook.